# How to detect ActiveSync connection on a mobile device?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, pinvoke

Im using the CompactFramework 3.5 on a WindowsCE 5.0 device to build an application that should use active sync's connection to get some data.

How can i detect if the mobile device is in the cradle and has an active connection? Is there some kind of PInvoke call for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on which side you want to detect the connection.  For the desktop side, there are some ActiveSync events you can hook into.  The free, open source [Desktop Communication library](http://www.opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/DesktopCommunication/tabid/90/Default.aspx) can get you those.

For the device there are a few ways.  For WinMo, it's easy - you can use the state and notification broker by tapping in via the [Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.aspx).

For generic CE devices, you can P/Invoke the [CeRunAppAtEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932775.aspx) (which can set an event, not just run an app) with the NOTIFICATION_EVENT_RS232_DETECTED flag.  These APIs are also wrapped in OpenNETCF's [Smart Device Framework](http://smartdeviceframework.com), specifically in the [DeviceManagement.SerialDeviceDetected event](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/cb212764-9260-0ce5-e2a8-9d9c4a23fcda.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You can also detect the cradle with this:

```
get
{
  return SystemState.GetValue(SystemProperty.CradlePresent).Equals(1);
}
```

Well okay this then

```
get
        {
            return  (int)SystemState.GetValue(SystemProperty.ConnectionsDesktopCount) > 0;
        }
```